# Color change causes icon to not show on svg version of font-awesome 5

Tags: svg, font-awesome-5

I'm using the latest version of font-awesome svg+js. I can only change the color of the icons with inline style.

Whenever I add a class, the icon stops showing and it becomes a flashing exclamation point.

This is a small fiddle showing the problem https://jsfiddle.net/CaioSantAnna/Lb5dpo7v/7/

```html
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/all.js"></script>

    <span class="fa-4x" style="background: #4CAF50">
      <i class="far fa-circle" style="color:white"></i>
      <i class="far fa-circle fa-white"></i>
    </span>

    <style type="text/css">
        .fa-white{
            fill:#ffffff;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
```

Is it possible to achieve the inline result with a common css class ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add a class to a wrapping element for example `<span class="fa-4x fa-white" style="background: #4CAF50">` Also you can add a class that do not begin with `fa-`:  <i class="far fa-circle white"></i>

Comment: I didn't know about the prefix usage issue. Could you please post an answer with your comment ? So I can accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the prefix `fa-`for an additional class will cause an error. The solution would be using an extra class without the prefix: for example `white` instead of `fa-white`

```css
    .white{
        fill:#ffffff;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/all.js"></script>

<span class="fa-4x" style="background: #4CAF50">
  <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
  <i class="far fa-circle white"></i>
</span>
```

An alternative solution would be using the prefixed class on the wrapping span:

```css
    .fa-white{
        fill:#ffffff;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/all.js"></script>

<span class="fa-4x  fa-white" style="background: #4CAF50">
  <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
  <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: the main issue is that the JS will try to look for an icon called `fa-white` that doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you for commenting. It's what I am saying: "the prefix fa-for an additional class will cause an error". My solution is to use class `white` instead of `fa-white` or, if the OP must use `fa-white` they may use it for the span  but not for the `i` element.